# Datatables row .filter() is not working or something else need to add

Tags: datatables

I am following [.filter() example](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()#Examples)

[This is live example](http://live.datatables.net/gaxibime/1/edit?js,console,output)

The live example seems not working.

I want to show only rows with Office in `London`

Have I missed something? or What more needs to be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I have update you fiddle : http://live.datatables.net/gaxibime/2/edit . you need to use `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` in your case.

Comment: @ReaganGallant : thanks for your help. You could post as answer and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have update you fiddle :
[fiddle link](http://live.datatables.net/gaxibime/2/edit)
 .

Filter method does not filter the rows.

You need to use `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The @Reagan Gallant's example works with Datatables version >= 1.10.
For Datatables < 1.10 use following

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();

table.fnFilter("London", 2, true);
```